# Python -- Classes -- TypeError

Tags: python, class, typeerror

I'm making a program that will do things with vectors. Right now i'm able to print out a vector, but i'm looking to be able to add to the vector if needed using my `add` function. However, it doesn't appear to work. It says that it can only take 1 argument, but two are given even though i am only entering one argument. Any advice?

`class Vec:`

```
def __init__(self, length = 0):
    self.vector = [0]*length

def __str__(self):
    return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(str(i) for i in self.vector))

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.vector)

def extd(self, newLen):
    self.vector.append([0]*newLen)
    return (', '.join(str(j) for j in self.vector))
```

Comment: Show the code where you are using `Vec`.

Comment: Also, your variable name `newLen` doesn't make any sense. Isn't that parameter the `item` you're adding to the vector?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `self` as your first parameter there.

```
def add(self, newLen):
```

Otherwise, what would be passed is not `newLen`, but a pointer to the instance itself, hence  the error.

By adding `self`, the first parameter that is automatically passed is the instance, and the second will be `newLen`.

See this console session, for example:

```
>>> class A:
    def pass_parameters(first_param, second_param=None):
        print(first_param, second_param)


>>> a = A()
>>> a.pass_parameters()
<__main__.A object at 0x000000000322BBE0> None
>>> a.pass_parameters('parameter')
<__main__.A object at 0x000000000322BBE0> parameter
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `self` parameter for your `add` method. It should look like this:

```
def add(self, newLen):
    self.vector.append(newLen)
    return '[{}]'.format(', '.join(str(i) for i in self.vector))
```

In Python, when you call an instance method, the instance is automatically passed for you as the first parameter (usually named self).

Example:

```
v = Vec()
v.add(4)   # Essentially calls Vec.add(v, 4)
```

Comment: such a silly mistake. Thank you! I've made the edits above, but i'm still having an output error. When i print, it works. When i extend, it adds another set of []'s around the vector. Where is this problem occurring??

Comment: @user3014014 That is a different issue. Please post a new question for that.